# Android Studio Firebase quizapp timer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to code a timer for my quizapp.

i have coded this. it update my questions every 5 secound.
i have 5 questions in the firebase. the method qupdate() is updating my buttons and question textview.

if i dont click any button the questions updates every 5 secound and after 25 second i am getting to the endmenu.

My problem is:  when i press a button the timer is not reseting. sample: i open the quiz i am clicking a button after 2 secounds and i am getting the new questions an after 3 secounds the timer is updating my question.

How can i reset the timer to 5 secounds when a button is pressed so that i have (if i clicked or not) 5 seconds left.

```
  int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
    int period = 5000; // repeat every sec.
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        int count = 0;

        public void run()
        {
            qupdate();
            count ++;

            if(count == 5)
                this.cancel();
        }

    }, delay, period);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to cancel the timer and start a new one.

So in your click handler:

```
timer.cancel();

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  ...
}, delay, period);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked  !!! after 10 questions my quiz ends and the next activity is my endmenu. The timer is buggin there and every 5 secounds my timer is reactivating. how can i stop all timers?

Comment: To stop a timer, you call `cancel()` on it. So to stop all timers, you call `cancel()` on each of them. Note that I'm not doing much more than checking the [documentation for the `Timer` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer), so I recommend studying that.